# Bootstrap-Table Vuejs OnExpandRow event integration

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-table

My goal is when the onExpandRow event is fired, I'm able to return a vue component.  I'm unable to find the row context or even render a component that is returned this way.

I cannot find any documentation about the OnExpandRow event with respect to the Vue integration.  If I am understanding it right, once you have rendered the table, it should just be further used like the js/jquery version of it.

example of the row configuration to try something stupid simple

```
onExpandRow: function (index, row) { return '{{row}}' },
```

Should this indeed be treated as if you were just relying on javascript and the vuejs bootstrap-table integration is only happening at the top level?

Comment: I haven't tried this scenario but I have been walking down the Vue.js/cli path lately and was tinkering with this last night. I need to get the onclick event working so if I get the syntax worked out within Vue.js I will pass it along. otherwise, I will be moving towards something like vue-good-table.

Comment: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/vuejs/component/#events - here is an example. `<BootstrapTable
  ref="table"
  :columns="columns"
  :data="data"
  :options="options"
  @onPostBody="onPostBody"
/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the article on my blog: [Formatter Use Vue Component](https://blog.bootstrap-table.com/2019/08/10/formatter-use-vue-component/).

It can be used in `detailFormatter`, a working example: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/wenzhixin/1174.